# Objective C NSString Validation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have a `NSString` which has user entered `UITextField` value, here i need to validate whether the string only contains values like

```
'a to z' , 'A to z' , '1 to 9'.
```

i don't want any other characters other than these... Please help me out...
i have use `NSNumberFormatter` for Numbers and `NSScanner` for Strings, but how to validate both at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Make `UITextField` delegate and paste this below code :-

// in -init, -initWithNibName:bundle:, or similar

```
NSCharacterSet *blockedCharacters = [[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet] retain];

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters
{
    return ([characters rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharacters].location == NSNotFound);
}
```

// in -dealloc

```
[blockedCharacters release];
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: how can i allow ' _ ' , ' @ ' ...?

Comment: @HarishSaran Check question you have asked

Comment: You can use `characterSetWithCharactersInString:` if you just want to type out the characters you're allowing. If you like the results of Prateek's solution, but just want to add _ and @ you could use NSMutableCharacterSet (just `union` together them together, making the second set with `characterSetWithCharactersInString:`. Hard to be sure from the docs, but I'm pretty sure that the `alphanumericCharacterSet` will include things you wouldn't typically think of as a-z, like ç

Answer (score 1):

you can use an `NSRegularExpression` like so:

```
    NSString *string1 = @"abc123";
    NSString *string2 = @"!abc123";
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^a-z0-9]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string1 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length])];
    NSLog(@"string 1 matches: %ld", numberOfMatches);

    numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string2 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length])];
    NSLog(@"string 2 matches: %ld", numberOfMatches);
```

and change the pattern `@"[^a-z0-9]"` to suit the characters you want to check for. The `^` means "not in this set", so if any matches are found the field should fail validation.